# Different commerce payment paypal settings on dev and live sites

Tags: rules, commerce

The problem is similar like here:
[How to force rules configuration to load](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68450/how-to-force-rules-configuration-to-load)

I planned to use hook_default_rules_configuration_alter(), but after this:

```
  if (isset($configs['commerce_payment_paypal_ec'])) {
    foreach ($configs['commerce_payment_paypal_ec']->actions() as $action) {
      dsm($action);
    }
  }
```

I don't see any $settings['settings'] array:

[image: Krumo]

How can I change the saved commerce_payment_paypal_ec rule's settings by code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that has came in different shapes, I'd recommend reading https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/118316/2322 answer to get a better understanding on how drupal commerce and rules store this information. I don't know how to access the UI form the action itself.

Instead of trying to modify specific values, what I'd do is to try to replace the whole rule object with the one you want using entity_import of the rules_config object, something like:

```
if (isset($configs['commerce_payment_paypal_ec'])) {
    $configs['commerce_payment_paypal_ec'] = entity_import('rules_config', '{ "commerce_payment_paypal_ec" : {
        "LABEL" : "PayPal Express Checkout",
        "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
        "OWNER" : "rules",
        "TAGS" : [ "Commerce Payment" ],
        "REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_payment" ],
        "ON" : { "commerce_payment_methods" : [] },
        "DO" : [
          { "commerce_payment_enable_paypal_ec" : {
              "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-order" ],
              "payment_method" : { "value" : {
                  "method_id" : "paypal_ec",
                  "settings" : {
                    "api_username" : "1",
                    "api_password" : "",
                    "api_signature" : "",
                    "server" : "sandbox",
                    "currency_code" : "EUR",
                    "allow_supported_currencies" : 0,
                    "txn_type" : "auth_capture",
                    "ec_mode" : "Mark",
                    "shipping_prompt" : "0",
                    "log" : { "request" : 0, "response" : 0 },
                    "ipn_logging" : "notification",
                    "receiver_emails" : "",
                    "reference_transactions" : 0,
                    "ba_desc" : "",
                    "show_payment_instructions" : 0,
                    "update_billing_profiles" : 1,
                    "enable_bml" : 0
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }');
  }
```

Comment: Sounds good, like I said here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121461/how-to-programmatically-add-modify-a-rule/121462?noredirect=1#comment144989_121462

But where?
I don't think the hook_default_rules_configuration_alter() is the right place to do it. :)

Comment: hook_default_rules_configuration_alter would be the first place where I'd put this, probably unsetting the old one before adding the new one if directly doesn't work.